# How can I access existing dom elements when using react render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will rendering a React component in to an existing website, an example of the root element might be:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

What I would like to do is, access any html inside the root element to begin with for example:

```
<div id="root">Hello world</div>
```

The documentation [seems to indicate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) you can do something along these lines:

> ReactDOM.render() does not modify the container node (only modifies
>   the children of the container). It may be possible to insert a
>   component to an existing DOM node without overwriting the existing
>   children.

I have tried to access using refs but I can't access these child DOM elements, does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
<div id="root" ref="root">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the existing child elements?

Comment: why not use state and pass it down to the child element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible in ReactDOM *directly*.

The "Hello world" string in your `<div id="root">` is treated as a child of the container node, and is therefore overwritten.

Instead, you'll need to get the `.innerHTML` from the `div` with the ID of `root` *before* ReactDOM's `render()` method is called. You can then do whatever you want with this afterwards:

```
let root = document.getElementById("root");
let existingContent = root.innerHTML;
ReactDOM.render(yourReactComponent, root);
console.log(existingContent); // Do whatever you need to do with this
```

Comment: sounds reasonable but I was hoping to avoid this, there documentation is a bit cryptic on this it seems, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4265

Comment: This is the exact problem I had (and GitHub issue I found) and ended up having to use the solution I posted. It's annoying, but until they actually "clarify" it further, I don't think there's a better way.

Comment: This seems like an accurate interpretation